# 2nd order pole inwhile computing residue in a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering - how does one deal with finding a residue of a contour integral when you introduce a fresh pole while computing the residue. For example:

$$
 \int   \,  \frac{ \frac{e^{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} }}{(x + i)^2}   dx}{  (x - i)^2}
$$
The contour includes the pole at $x = i$ but excludes the one at $x = -i$.

This simplifies to:

$$
2 \pi i \, \frac{d}{dx} \Big[  \frac{e^{ \sqrt{x^2 + 1} }}{(x + i)^2}  \Big]
$$

but unfortunately while taking the differential we end up getting $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ in the denominator and hence a fresh pole. How does one get the residue then?

Thanks!
Karthik

Comment: You have to exclude the branch point from the interior of your contour.

Comment: sorry, would it be possible to elaborate a bit?  I wanted to evaluate the  integral from real x = -infinity to +infinity.  I thought one way would be to use a contour integral including the pole x = i in the contour which would give a residue.   Can you explain a bit how I can exclude it and still get a residue?

Thanks